# ¿Cómo hago para que me funcione SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: java, android-studio, audio

Soy nuevo en el tema del desarrollo de aplicaciones para android. Necesito usar una SpeechRecognizer; lo implemente pero alparecer no me reconoce el dispositivo de audio, tanto del emulador como cuando lo uso en un dispositivo físico. Me podrían dar sugerencias de cómo puedo solucionar ese problema.

Ésta es la clase que estoy utilizando para ello:

```
private void startVoiceRecognition() {

    // Primero, comprobar si se han concedido los permisos necesarios para usar el micrófono
    System.out.println("Precionó botón escuchar");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Precionó botón escuchar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Si no se han concedido los permisos, pedirlos al usuario
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
        System.out.println("Dió los permisos");
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Habla ahora");
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        System.out.println("No inició el reconocimiento de voz");
        recognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
                // Se llama cuando el reconocedor está listo para recibir la entrada de voz
                // Puedes agregar aquí algún código que se ejecute cuando el reconocimiento de voz esté listo
                System.out.println("Reconocimiento de voz listo");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Reconocimiento de voz listo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Julio, bienvenido, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Hola, ya agregué la clase que estoy implementado para ello. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué parte es la que no funciona? En el listener deberías agregar una implementación a [`onResults`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener#onResults(android.os.Bundle)) y opcionalmente `onPartialResults`.

Comment: En onResults guardo el texto que se reconoce y lo muestro en consola:  `if (matches != null && matches.size() > 0) {
                        String textoReconocido = matches.get(0); // Obtener el primer resultado
                        System.out.println("Texto reconocido: " + textoReconocido);` Pero el problema es que el dispositivo no reconoce. Me sale el siguiente mensaje: "E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service"